# boost::circular_buffer<unique_ptr<T>>::set_capacity() fails to build

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to use `boost::circular_buffer` in my code like this:

```
class EventRegistry
{
public:
    EventRegistry()
    {
        pendingEvents_.set_capacity(MAX_PENDING_EVENTS);
    }

private:
    boost::circular_buffer<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<EventData>> pendingEvents_;
}
```

However, I'm getting a build failure (excerpted):

```
...
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/circular_buffer/details.hpp:470:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::cb_details::uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_impl<boost::cb_details::iterator<boost::circular_buffer<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >, std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >, boost::cb_details::nonconst_traits<boost::container::allocator_traits<std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > > > >, boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > *, std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >' requested here
    return uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_impl(first, last, dest, a, tag_t());
           ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/circular_buffer/base.hpp:955:37: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::cb_details::uninitialized_move_if_noexcept<boost::cb_details::iterator<boost::circular_buffer<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >, std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >, boost::cb_details::nonconst_traits<boost::container::allocator_traits<std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > > > >, boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > *, std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >' requested here
            reset(buff, cb_details::uninitialized_move_if_noexcept(e - (std::min)(new_capacity, size()),
                                    ^
events/event_registry.cc:22:18: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::circular_buffer<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >, std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >::rset_capacity' requested here
  pendingEvents_.rset_capacity(MAX_PENDING_EVENTS);
...
```

However, if I use an initializer in the constructor:

```
EventRegistry()
  : pendingEvents_(MAX_PENDING_EVENTS)
```

Then it compiles fine. Any clues?

**UPDATE**: Here's the full output (sorry for the length)

```
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:408:51: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >'
      {  ::new((void*)p, boost_container_new_t()) T(::boost::forward<Args>(args)...); }
                                                  ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:353:28: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::container::allocator_traits<std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >::priv_construct<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >, boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > >' requested here
         allocator_traits::priv_construct(flag, a, p, ::boost::forward<Args>(args)...);
                           ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/circular_buffer/details.hpp:439:56: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::container::allocator_traits<std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >::construct<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >, boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > >' requested here
            boost::container::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct(a, boost::addressof(*dest), *first);
                                                       ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/circular_buffer/details.hpp:460:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::cb_details::uninitialized_copy<boost::cb_details::iterator<boost::circular_buffer<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >, std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >, boost::cb_details::nonconst_traits<boost::container::allocator_traits<std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > > > >, boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > *, std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >' requested here
    return uninitialized_copy(first, last, dest, a);
           ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/circular_buffer/details.hpp:470:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::cb_details::uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_impl<boost::cb_details::iterator<boost::circular_buffer<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >, std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >, boost::cb_details::nonconst_traits<boost::container::allocator_traits<std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > > > >, boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > *, std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >' requested here
    return uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_impl(first, last, dest, a, tag_t());
           ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/circular_buffer/base.hpp:880:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::cb_details::uninitialized_move_if_noexcept<boost::cb_details::iterator<boost::circular_buffer<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >, std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >, boost::cb_details::nonconst_traits<boost::container::allocator_traits<std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > > > >, boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > *, std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >' requested here
                cb_details::uninitialized_move_if_noexcept(b, b + (std::min)(new_capacity, size()), buff, m_alloc),
                            ^
.../events/event_registry.cc:22:18: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::circular_buffer<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >, std::allocator<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> > > >::set_capacity' requested here
  pendingEvents_.set_capacity(MAX_EVENTS_PER_TIMEWINDOW);
                 ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:360:35: note: candidate constructor not viable: 1st argument ('const boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >') would lose const qualifier
   BOOST_MOVABLE_BUT_NOT_COPYABLE(unique_ptr)
                                  ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/move/core.hpp:242:46: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_MOVABLE_BUT_NOT_COPYABLE'
      BOOST_MOVE_IMPL_NO_COPY_CTOR_OR_ASSIGN(TYPE)\
                                             ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/move/core.hpp:35:7: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_MOVE_IMPL_NO_COPY_CTOR_OR_ASSIGN'
      TYPE(TYPE &);\
      ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:401:20: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >' to 'bmupd::nullptr_type' (aka 'int (boost::move_upd::bool_conversion::*)()') for 1st argument
   BOOST_CONSTEXPR unique_ptr(BOOST_MOVE_DOC0PTR(bmupd::nullptr_type)) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
                   ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:527:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >' to '::boost::rv<unique_ptr<EventData, default_delete<EventData> > > &' for 1st argument
   unique_ptr(BOOST_RV_REF(unique_ptr) u) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
   ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:424:13: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Pointer = boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >]: no type named 'type' in 'boost::move_upd::enable_up_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::unique_ptr<appd::agent::EventData, boost::movelib::default_delete<appd::agent::EventData> >, appd::agent::EventData *, boost::move_upmu::nat>'
   explicit unique_ptr(Pointer p
            ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:462:4: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires at least 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
   unique_ptr(Pointer p, BOOST_MOVE_SEEDOC(deleter_arg_type1) d1
   ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:500:4: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires at least 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
   unique_ptr(Pointer p, BOOST_MOVE_SEEDOC(deleter_arg_type2) d2
   ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:547:4: note: candidate template ignored: instantiation would take its own class type by value
   unique_ptr( BOOST_RV_REF_BEG_IF_CXX11 unique_ptr<U, E> BOOST_RV_REF_END_IF_CXX11 u
   ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:390:20: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
   BOOST_CONSTEXPR unique_ptr() BOOST_NOEXCEPT
                   ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:475:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
   unique_ptr(BOOST_MOVE_DOC0PTR(bmupd::nullptr_type), BOOST_MOVE_SEEDOC(deleter_arg_type1) d1) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
   ^
boost/build/binaries/include/boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:513:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
   unique_ptr(BOOST_MOVE_DOC0PTR(bmupd::nullptr_type), BOOST_MOVE_SEEDOC(deleter_arg_type2) d2) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
   ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: The part of the error message that you've included does not include the error, it just includes part of the instantiation chain that led to it.

Comment: Updated the post with the full output.

Comment: One obvious difference between the two is when you set capacity in the constructor, the `circular_buffer` doesn't need to bother with trying to move/copy existing elements. It seems to be this part that's failing, but I don't get why it's unable to move the `unique_ptr`s. What version of Boost are you using, because [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e316b94d0b34287) compiles. Maybe you're using an older version where `boost::move::unique_ptr`'s move constructor was not marked `noexcept`?

Comment: Also, please try to make life easier for people trying to help you by posting examples that can be copy-pasted as is and compiled.

Comment: You forgot ';' after '}'.

Answer (score 2):

The following compiles just fine...

```
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp>

class EventRegistry
{
public:
    EventRegistry()
    {
        pendingEvents_.set_capacity(10);
    }

private:
    boost::circular_buffer<boost::movelib::unique_ptr<int>> pendingEvents_;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I've placed an `int` where you have `EventData`.
You're problem is probably related to `EventData`.

(I don't have enough points, to comment...)

Edit: Oh and check what kind of constructors `EventData` has! Do you have a default constructor??

Comment: No, EventData does not have a default constructor because it is required to be initialized with certain values. I guess that's why it's failing.

The only workaround I can think about for resizing the circular buffer is to create another buffer, move the contents of the original to it and delete the original.